# erroneous message editing SMB file

Tags: files, save

I'm running GNU Emacs 29.1 on a Mac mini. I've used Emacs uninterruptedly since 1987. I don't normally participate in discussion groups like this.

When I edit a file in a directory that is in a SMB filesystem mounted from a NAS, I get the following message:

[filename] has changed since visited or saved. Save anyway? (yes or no)

This happens about once a minute, and I have to answer "yes" almost every time I want to save the file. It's never the case that the file has actually changed since last visited or saved. Is this a known problem, and is there a solution for it?

If there is a better place to ask this question, please say so. I need to find a discussion forum where I can find knowledgeable answers.

Comment: This is a good place for your question, I think. Another is help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org (send a mail to that list). This site (emacs.SE) isn't a discussion site, however; it's for Q & A. For discussion (opinions etc.) you might want to try Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs checks the “last modified” time of the file just before you save, comparing it against the time when Emacs last wrote to the file. If the “last modified” time of the file is newer than that, Emacs gives you the warning you are seeing. You should examine the files on your NAS to see what their “last modified” times are. Perhaps some process on the NAS is causing that time to be updated. Or maybe the clock on the NAS is simply out of sync with the clock on your computer.

Ultimately there's really nothing wrong with Emacs here; it is doing all it can to keep your files safe. You need to troubleshoot your NAS.